# How split a pandas dataframe in muliple excel files

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame with sales related to different countries. I need to crate a different excel for each of the country I have in the dataframe.
I am not sure how I can accomplish this in pandas

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  It's clear that you need to familiarize yourself with how we ask questions.  This site is a great resource and you'll be able to leverage it more efficiently if you follow some simple guidelines.  Please read [***MCVE***](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [***HowToAsk***](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a better idea of what we expect.  This is intended to help you get your question(s) answered.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        Sales=[1, 2, 3, 4],
        Country=['jp', 'cn', 'uk', 'au']
    ))

print(df)

  Country  Sales
0      jp      1
1      cn      2
2      uk      3
3      au      4
```

We can iterate through a `groupby` object and use `to_excel`

```
for n, g in df.groupby('Country'):
    # `n` is the group name, which will be the country
    g.to_excel('{}.xlsx'.format(n))
```

This will have created the files

```
['au.xlsx', 'cn.xlsx', 'jp.xlsx', 'uk.xlsx']
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative version:

```
for c in df['Country'].unique():
    df.loc[df['Country'] == c].to_excel('/path/to/{}.xlsx'.format(c), index=False)
```